# JCC failed to link python3.5 for pylucene installation

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, makefile, g++, pylucene

I'm trying to install JCC, which is a prerequisite of pylucene. I'm working with linux-mint Serena. I want to install it with python3.5. After checking the setup.py file I run:

```
python3.5 setup.py build
```

Here is the error I get:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/jcc3/sources/jcc.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/jcc3/sources/JCCEnv.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/libjcc3.so -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64 -ljava -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -Wl,-rpath=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server -Wl,-S -lpython3.5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.5
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-g++' failed with exit status 1
```

I checked that python3.5 was available in `/usr/bin/`, also I checked that I have python3-dev installed.

I don't know why the linkage is failing, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to install pylucene using python2.7. Then I discovered this github: https://github.com/rudimeier/jcc which I used to compile JCC with python3.5 which allowed me to compile pylucene with python3.5.